# Python: Convert column from float to int

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am using a pandas, and need to concat two dataframes based on a `set_id` index.  One of the dataframes has these as floats (see below).  How can I convert these to ints?

[image]

Comment: Depends, do you want to round to the nearest int or truncate the decimal completely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with

```
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
```